# Using $\sec(x)$ for integral.

Tags: integration, analysis, solution-verification

> Find the undefined integral $\int \frac{\sqrt{x^2+4x}}{x^2}\mathrm{dx}$

$$\displaystyle\int \dfrac{\displaystyle\sqrt{x^2+4x}}{x^2}\mathrm{dx}$$

I tried to rearrange the square root and I got:

$$\sqrt{(x+2)^2-4}$$ and I substitute the $x+2$ with $2\sec(u)$ so indeed I got these two:

$$x+2=2\sec(u) \\
\sqrt{x^2+4x}=2\tan(u) \\
\mathrm{dx}=2\tan(u)\sec(u)\mathrm{du}$$

And the integral turns out like this:

$$\displaystyle \int \dfrac{\tan^2(u)\sec(u)}{(\sec(u)-1)^2}\mathrm{du}$$

And I continued to rearrange the integral:

$$\displaystyle\int \dfrac{1-\cos^2(u)}{\cos(u)(1-\cos(u))^2}\mathrm{du}$$

I apply partial fractions method, saying $\cos(u)=u$ without integral sign and I ended up with:

$$\displaystyle\int \dfrac{1}{\cos(u)}\mathrm{du}+2\displaystyle\int \dfrac{1}{1-\cos(u)}\mathrm{du}$$

One can easily integrate those integrals se I skip the calculating part. In the end I get:

$$\ln\left|\sec(u)+\tan(u)\right|+2(-\cot(u)-\csc(u))+\mathrm{C}$$

I drew a triangle:

Knowing $\sec(u)=\dfrac{x+2}{2}$ says us $\cos(u)=\dfrac{2}{x+2}$

[image]

As I calculate I got:

$$\ln\left|x+2+\sqrt{x^2+4x}\right|-\dfrac{2x-8}{\sqrt{x^2+4x}}+\mathrm{C}$$

Bu the answer key is:

$$\ln\left|x+2+\sqrt{x^2+4x}\right|-\dfrac{8}{x+\sqrt{x^2+4x}}+\mathrm{C}$$

I have been thinking where my wrong is for five hours but I couldn't find anything. Please if you see any gap tell me. Thanks.

Comment: I haven't got the time to try it out right at the moment, but you might find you have better luck substituting $x + 2 = 2 \cosh u$. Then your thing inside the square root becomes a sinh, and it may be more tractable. Or try $z = (x+2)^2$.

Comment: I will try it. Indeed I tried to substitute this as $\sqrt{x^2+4x}=t-x$ and it worked. But as I said, why the trig sub. doesn't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The difference between the two answers is:

\begin{align}
&\quad\frac {2x\color{red}{+}8}{\sqrt{x^2+4x}}-\frac {8}{x+\sqrt{x^2+4x}}
\\&=\frac {(2x+8)(x+\sqrt{x^2+4x}) - 8\sqrt{x^2+4x}}{(x+\sqrt{x^2+4x})\sqrt{x^2+4x}}
\\&=\frac {2x^2+8x+2x\sqrt{x^2+4x}}
{(x+\sqrt{x^2+4x})\sqrt{x^2+4x}}
\\&=\frac {2(x^2+4x+x\sqrt{x^2+4x})}
{x\sqrt{x^2+4x}+x^2+4x}
\\&=2
\end{align}

which is a constant. So both answers are correct.

Comment: I didn't see anything like that before. How can it be correct, I didn't understand?

Comment: The antiderivative is not unique, hence the constant of integration $+C$ at the end. If you obtain an answer which differs by a constant, it is still a correct answer, since the constant will get absorbed into the $+C$. For example, $\int 2xdx = x^2 + 1 + C$ is technically not a wrong answer, since its derivative is still $2x$.

Comment: That's so true! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

Another way:

For $x>0,$

$$I=\int\dfrac{\sqrt{x^2+4x}}{x^2}\ dx=\int\dfrac{\sqrt{x+4}}{x^{3/2}}\ dx$$

Integrating by parts,

$$I=\sqrt{x+4}\int\dfrac{dx}{x^{3/2}}-\int\left(\dfrac{d\sqrt{x+4}}{dx}\int\dfrac{dx}{x^{3/2}}\right)dx$$

$$=-\sqrt{x+4}\cdot\dfrac{2}{\sqrt x}+\int\dfrac{dx}{\sqrt{(x+2)^2-2^2}}$$

Now observe that $\dfrac8{\sqrt{x^2+4x}+x}=\dfrac{8(\sqrt{x^2+4x}-x)}{4x}=2\sqrt{\dfrac{x+4}x}-2$

Answer (score 1):

The error occurred in partial decomposition. Instead, it should be

$$
\dfrac{1-\cos^2(u)}{\cos(u)(1-\cos(u))^2}=
\dfrac{1}{\cos(u)}+\dfrac{2}{1-\cos(u)}$$

Comment: Sorry, I did it in this way but I forgot to wrote it. Even if I wrote in this way I got the result that I mentioned.